# com_ajax - LogicException: Module is not published, you do not have access to it

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I made simple module (contact form), and when I try to access it via AJAX I get following error:

> LogicException: Module mod_contact_us_form is not published, you do
>   not have access to it, or it's not assigned to the current menu item

This is url which I am using to access it:

```
index.php?option=com_ajax&format=raw&module=contact_us_form
```

This is helper class:

```
class modContactUsFormHelper
{

    public function getParams($instance = 'mod_contact_us_form')
    {
      jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
      $module = JModuleHelper::getModule($instance);
      $moduleParams = new JRegistry;
      $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);

      return $moduleParams;
    }

    public static function sendEmail($data)
    {
        $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

        $params = static::getParams();
        $mailer->setSender($data['email']);
        $mailer->addRecipient($data['kancelarija']);
        $mailer->setSubject($data['tema']);

        $body = '<h3>' . $data['tema'] .  '</h3>';
        $body .= '<p>' . $data['ime']  .  ' вас је контактирао са следећим питањем:</p>';
        $body .= '<p>' . $data['pitanje']  .  '</p>';
        $body .= '<p>Контакт email  адреса: ' . $data['email']   . '</p>';

        $mailer->setBody($body);
        $mailer->send();
    }

    public static function getAjax()
    {
        $data = modContactUsFormHelper::cleanData();
        modContactUsFormHelper::sendEmail($data);

        echo  'Kontakt Forma';
    }

    public static function cleanData()
    {
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

        $data = array(
            'name'        => $input->get('ime', '', 'string'),
            'email'       => $input->get('email', '', 'string'),
            'tema'        => $input->get('tema', '', 'string'),
            'pitanje'     => $input->get('pitanje', '', 'string'),
            'kancelarija' => $input->get('contact')
        );
        return $data;
    }

}
// END OF CLASS modContactUsFormHelper
```

The part which is confusing me - I have made similar module (this is kinda upgraded module from my first one) and I am using the same call for AJAX (except module=contact_us_form part). First module is working without any problem (this model is not turned, nor installed along with the new one). What seems to be a problem?

**EDIT:**

I have found solution - It seems that when you assign module to specific page, it will not register it as published. But if you select **On all pages except those selected** and then assign it only to desire menu, it will register it as published and it will work.

Comment: I would ask in the joomla dev mailing group https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/joomla-dev-general. Thats the place where the developers turned the ajax idea into a component. You will get there help from the authors of this functionality directly, especially from matt from betweenbrain who  had the lead about com_ajax.

Answer (score 11):

to access modules which specified to menu assignments you must also add the Itemid to url, like index.php?option=com_ajax&format=raw&module=contact_us_form`&Itemid=123`

Comment: To get the Itemid : $app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. This problem arises when a module using AJAX is published **ONLY** on the homepage (default menu item) of a Joomla website. For some reason, in this specific situation, the `Itemid` (that of the default menu item) MUST be specified in the AJAX request URL for the request to work. The specific `ItemId` value to use is that of the "Id" column visible in the Joomla Administrator (backend) associated to the default menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but I think there is a bug in `com_ajax` Joomla that will be solved with the next release.

See [Issue 32166](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=32166&start=0)

Meanwhile try renaming your module to

`contact_us_form` => `contactusform`.

Another alternative is to apply the patch. See for this the [Component Patchtester for Testers](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Patchtester_for_Testers) and apply the patch ID: 2133

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/2133

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nothing seems to work. The old module have name mod_ask_us and it is working without the problem. I renamed him to mod_askus and it is still working. I guess Joomla does not use logic :D

Comment: I manage to make it work, but there is still a problem. When I assign module to all pages it is working, but when I assign it to specific menu it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you send the form, your module is not yet published in the BackEnd.