# Ajax text echo mod_whoisonline, Joomla3

Tags: php, joomla, counter

Inspirational solution for Ajax OnlineViewers count using this trigger url in Joomla3: [https://adepca.com/index.php?method=view&option=com_ajax&module=whosonline&task=view&format=raw](https://adepca.com/index.php?method=view&option=com_ajax&module=mod_whoisonline&task=view&format=raw)

It produces this error: LogicException: Module mod_whoisonline is not published, you do not have access to it, or it 's not assigned to the current menu item.

No numbers. Edit the /language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_whoisonline.ini to be of only the query for number of guest visitors.

Add a Javascript with URL to update at certain millisecond in the header of HTML and make it dance.

But still crying to deal with the error even though it has been published it hangs or else it would not show on my frontpage. Little do we know about humans and universes but computers. Coffee break. Seems the com_ajax doesn't read module status correctly ? CRC check ? MD5 sum check ?

Anyone having a working solution?

Testing testing right now:

```js
<code>
<script type="text/javascript">
var intervalTime = 1200 * 60 * 1000;
var timerID;
function start() {
    refresher();
    timerID = setInterval("refresher", intervalTime );
}
function refreshBtnClick() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    start();
}
function refresher() {
    $.post('', function(data) {
    $('#OnlineViewers').html(data);
  });
}
function send(data) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/index.php",
data: <?= $guest; ?>,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {
console.log(html);
}
  });
}
start();
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    span.RegisterFree {
    background: #107516; padding: 7px;
    color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
span.Members {
    background: #ff0000; padding: 4px;
    color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
span.OnlineViewers {
    background: #000000; padding: 4px;
    color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
div#OnlineViewers {
    background: #000000; padding: 4px;
    color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
</style>
Time: <b><?php echo date("H:m:s"); ?>GMT+1</b> Date: <b><?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?></b><br />
NetworkData: <strong><?php include("/web44/web/interface.php"); ?></strong><br />
<?php if ($showmode == 0 || $showmode == 2) : ?>
        <div id="OnlineViewers"><?php $guest = JText::plural('MOD_WHOSONLINE_GUESTS', $count['guest']); ?></div>
        <?php $member = JText::plural('MOD_WHOSONLINE_MEMBERS', $count['user ']); ?>
        <p><?php echo JText::sprintf('MOD_WHOSONLINE_WE_HAVE', $guest, $member); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (($showmode > 0) && count($names)) : ?>
        <?php if ($params->get('filter_groups')) : ?>
                <p><?php echo JText::_('MOD_WHOSONLINE_SAME_GROUP_MESSAGE'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <ul class="whosonline<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($names as $name) : ?>
                <li>
                        <?php echo $name->username; ?>
                </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
<?php endif;
?>
Total Visitors: <strong><?php

// Add correct path to your countlog.txt file.
$path = '/web44/web/modules/mod_whosonline/tmpl/counter.txt';

// Opens countlog.txt to read the number of hits.
$file  = fopen( $path, 'r' );
$count = fgets( $file, 1000 );
fclose( $file );

// Update the count.
$count = abs( intval( $count ) ) + 1;

// Output the updated count.
echo "{$count}";

// Opens countlog.txt to change new hit number
$file = fopen( $path, 'w' );
fwrite( $file, $count );
fclose( $file ); ?></strong>
</code>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Meister Propper geile gardine. Hm. Updated the OP with new info. Hopefully usefull.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282080/com-ajax-logicexception-module-is-not-published-you-do-not-have-access-to-it

Comment: You might try asking your Joomla question on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Last code I've tried with is the one I'm posting below. Works mostly.

/modules/mod_whoisonline/tmpl/default.php

```
<code>
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_whosonline
 *
 * @copyright   (C) 2006 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>

<div class="usersonline"></div>
<script>
function onlinevisitor(){
    $('#OnlineVisitor').load('hitcount.txt',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

onlinevisitor(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
        var elem = $("#OnlineVisitor");
        if (elem) elem.append('<?php echo JText::sprintf('MOD_WHOSONLINE_WE_HAVE', $guest, $member); ?>');
    onlinevisitor() // this will run after every 120 seconds
}, 10000);
</script>

<script>
function onlinecounter(){
    $('#OnlineCounter').load('counter.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

onlinecounter(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
        var elem = $("#OnlineCounter");
        if (elem) elem.append('<?php include("hitcount.txt"); ?>');
    onlinecounter() // this will run after every 120 seconds
}, 10000);
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    span.RegisterFree {
    background: #107516; padding: 7px;
    color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
span.Members {
    background: #ff0000; padding: 4px;
    color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
span.OnlineViewers {
    background: #000000; padding: 4px;
    color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
strong#OnlineViewers {
    background: #000000; padding: 4px;
    color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
</style>
Time: <b><?php echo date("H:m:s"); ?>GMT+1</b> Date: <b><?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?></b><br />
<?php if ($showmode == 0 || $showmode == 2) : ?>
    <?php $guest = JText::plural('MOD_WHOSONLINE_GUESTS', $count['guest']); ?>
        <?php $member = JText::plural('MOD_WHOSONLINE_MEMBERS', $count['user']); ?>
        <p><?php echo JText::sprintf('MOD_WHOSONLINE_WE_HAVE', $guest, $member); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (($showmode > 0) && count($names)) : ?>
        <?php if ($params->get('filter_groups')) : ?>
                <p><?php echo JText::_('MOD_WHOSONLINE_SAME_GROUP_MESSAGE'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <ul class="whosonline<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($names as $name) : ?>
                <li>
                        <?php echo $name->username; ?>
                </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
<?php endif;?>
Total Visitors: <strong id="OnlineViewers" style="font-family:Roboto;font-size:64px;"><?php $count_page = ("hitcount.txt"); $hits = file($count_page); $hits[0] ++; $fp = fopen($count_page , "w"); fputs($fp , "$hits[0]"); fclose($fp); echo $hits[0]; ?> visitors</strong> since 09th July 2022. Updates every 120sec.
<a href="/register.html"><span class="RegisterFree">Create Free Community Account</span></a>
</code>
```

/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_whoisonline.ini

```
<code>
; Joomla! Project
; (C) 2005 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
; License GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
; Note : All ini files need to be saved as UTF-8

MOD_WHOSONLINE="Who's Online"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_FILTER_GROUPS_DESC="Choose to filter by groups of the connected user"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_FILTER_GROUPS_LABEL="Filter Groups"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_LINKTOWHAT_DESC="Choose the type of information to display"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_LINKTOWHAT_LABEL="Information"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_VALUE_BOTH="Both"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_VALUE_CONTACT="Contact"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_VALUE_NAMES="Usernames"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_VALUE_NUMBER="# of Guests / Users"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_FIELD_VALUE_PROFILE="Profile"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_GUESTS="%s&#160;guests"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_GUESTS_1="one guest"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_GUESTS_0="no guests"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_MEMBERS="%s&#160;members"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_MEMBERS_1="one member"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_MEMBERS_0="no members"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_SAME_GROUP_MESSAGE="List of Users who belong to your user groups or your user groups' child groups"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_SHOWMODE_DESC="Select what will be shown"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_SHOWMODE_LABEL="Display"
MOD_WHOSONLINE_XML_DESCRIPTION="The Who's Online Module displays the number of Anonymous Users (e.g. Guests) and Registered Users (ones logged-in) that are currently accessing the website."
; frontend display
; in the following string
; %1$s is for guests and %2$s for members
MOD_WHOSONLINE_WE_HAVE="We have <span class="OnlineViewers" style='font-family:Roboto;font-size:64px;'>%1$s</span> and <span class="Members" style='font-family:Roboto;font-size:64px;'>%2$s</span> online"
</code>
```

You need to add the: `<div id="OnlineCounter"></div>` and `<div id="OnlineViewer"></div>` to the code. Settled with the code I've posted and disregard the live ajax update as it seems to break my HTML for some reason and eat the page after a while so until I've studied the code further and found a suitable solution this was the way to go.